# How to import firestores type to the utils file?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Currently the logic contains the function that processes specific part of data record stored in firestore:

```
private listenUserData (): void {
    this.unListenUserData = FirebaseDb
      .collection(`users`).doc(this.user.id)
      .collection(`userData`)
      .onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, (querySnapshot) => {
        const changes = getUserDataSnapshotChanges(querySnapshot)
        const { data, changeType } = changes

        data.config && this.handleConfigChanges(data.config, changeType)
        data.personalData && this.handlePersonalDataChanges(data.personalData)
      })
  }
```

... it uses a utility that processes the querySnapshot and returns and object:

```
export function getUserDataSnapshotChanges (querySnapshot: any): UserDataSnapshotChangesType {
  const changes: UserDataSnapshotChangesType = {
    data: {},
    changeType: ``,
    isEmpty: querySnapshot.empty
  }

  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((docChange: any) => {
    const { doc } = docChange

    changes.data[doc.id] = doc.data()
    changes.changeType = docChange.type
  })

  return changes
}
```

as you could see for now the QuerySnapshot and docChange use any type, since trying something like `import { DocumentChange } from 'firebase'`

I've explored a bit the index.d.ts of firebase and the following type is a part of namespace `firebase.firestore`:
[image]

I will appreciate a lot if somebody can share some ideas on this case:
1. Does it means there is no actual way to import that type if it's a part of not exported namespace?
2. And if now what can be a possible way to access firestore for the sake of type safe code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have created your `FirebaseDb` instance with the `firebase.firestore()` method. As far as i know the types should be available inside the `firebase.firestore` namespace.

The type for `querysnapshot` would be `firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

The type for `docChange` would be `firebase.firestore.DocumentChange`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange

```
export function getUserDataSnapshotChanges (querySnapshot: firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot): UserDataSnapshotChangesType {
  const changes: UserDataSnapshotChangesType = {
    data: {},
    changeType: ``,
    isEmpty: querySnapshot.empty
  }

  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((docChange: firebase.firestore.DocumentChange) => {
    const { doc } = docChange

    changes.data[doc.id] = doc.data()
    changes.changeType = docChange.type
  })

  return changes
}
```

I access the Firebase types this way and it works fine for me.

**EDIT**

I do not know which version your Firebase node module has but this works for version 7.13.

If you just want to import the classes you could use these imports.

```
import {QuerySnapshot, DocumentChange} from '@firebase/firestore-types';
```

And use it like this.

```
export function getUserDataSnapshotChanges (querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot): UserDataSnapshotChangesType {
  const changes: UserDataSnapshotChangesType = {
    data: {},
    changeType: ``,
    isEmpty: querySnapshot.empty
  }

  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((docChange: DocumentChange) => {
    const { doc } = docChange

    changes.data[doc.id] = doc.data()
    changes.changeType = docChange.type
  })

  return changes
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: What user is asking is about using Typed classes , like `import { DocumentChange } from 'firebase'`

Comment: @Reza I do not know why you had to down vote my answer. My solution works perfectly fine because he already imported the namespace when he created his firestore instance. But for completion i also added the solution with the class import.

Comment: Reze, both solution are actually valid by the way :-)

Comment: P.S: I will award a bounty this afternoon, when award action gets unblocked